# It seem not fetch the $_POST

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

I'm stuck in login page. From home,user will login (form send to check_login) and from check_login user will be directed to page based on their role. However, I cannot pass through the login page. I mean I keep getting the error message from header('location: 1.php?error=1');

fyi, i've successfully connected to db. The data is there. But if I echo oci_num_rows, the result is 0..

Here is my code login.php

```
<form action="check_login.php" method="post" name="login">
        <div class="error"><?php include('error-handler.php'); ?></div>

        <p> Matric / Staff ID :</p>
        <p><input type="text" name="id" size="20" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required value=""/></p>

        <p>Password  :</p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="20" maxlength="8" min="6" required value="" />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //add a show password checkbox 
                new ShowPasswordCheckbox(document.getElementById("password"));
                //test the submitted value
                document.getElementById('login').onsubmit = function()
                {
                alert('pword = "' + this.pword.value + '"');
                return false;
                };
        </script>
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/></p> </form>
```

and here is my check_login.php

```
    <?php
ob_start();
// Inialize session
session_start();
require_once('connection.php');

//if the login form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt2= oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM user1 WHERE id = '$id'")or die(oci_error());
    $check2 = oci_execute($stmt2);

     //Gives error if user dosen't exist
     $check3 = oci_num_rows($stmt2);

       if ($check3 == 0)
       {  
       header('location: 1.php?error=1'); //the msg will be: you are not eligible user.
        exit();
       }
       else
       {
        while($info2=oci_fetch_array($stmt2,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
            {
            //gives error if the password is wrong
            if ($pass != $info2['password'])
            {
            header('location: 1.php?error=2'); //password mismatch with id
            exit();
            }
            else
            {
            // if login is ok then we add a cookie
            $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
            $hour = time() + 86400;

            setcookie(ID_site, $_SESSION['id'], $hour);
            setcookie(Pass_site, $_SESSION['password'], $hour);

            //then redirect them to the members area
                if ($info2['role']=='admin')
                {
                header('Location: homeAdmin.php');
                }
                elseif ($info2['role']=='staff')
                {
                header('Location: homeStaff.php');
                }
                elseif ($info2['role']=='student')
                {
                header('Location: homeStudent.php');
                }
                else
                {
                header('Location: 1.php');
                }

            } //end else

         } //end while

}//end else

}// end if submit
 else
{
 header('Location: 1.php');
 } 

 ?>
```

Please share your opinion or pls correct if i'm wrong. Thank you. :)

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot pass through the login page"? The code doesn't execute? You get an error? Please explain the _actual_ problem.

Comment: What happens and what is supposed to happen? Any error messages?

Comment: can you please also share your form..??

Comment: show your form code here

Comment: you should save the passwords in the database as a checksum. See http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

From PHP manual 'oci_num_rows' : http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php

> This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT
>   statements this function will return the number of rows, that were
>   fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.

Comment: But then how can I confirm that the Select statment works? Is there any codes for that?

Comment: I have not used the oci functions myself, so not really sure. Check the link i provided, maybe something in the comments that could help you.